# Add custom action to System Menu in a QDialog

Tags: windows, qt, menu, titlebar, qdialog

I have a need to add a custom action (say ‘About’ clicking which a QMessageBox needs to be displayed) in the system menu shown when the icon on the title bar of a QDialog is clicked. How do I achieve this?

Regards,
Bharath

[image: Window components]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it with Qt because it's OS specific. But you can use [GetSystemMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647985(v=vs.85).aspx) and [AppendMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647616(v=vs.85).aspx) functions in Windows to modify the menu and then catch events that then item is clicked.

Here is a simple example from [here](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21165). It appends a separator and an about item to the menu:

```
#include "windows.h"

// IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range
//       (IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
//   and (IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000)
#define IDM_ABOUTBOX 0x0010

MyWidget::MyWidget() : QMainWindow()
{
 ...
HMENU hMenu = ::GetSystemMenu(winId(), FALSE);
if (hMenu != NULL)
{
  ::AppendMenuA(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, 0);
  ::AppendMenuA(hMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, "About MyApp...");
}

...
}

bool MyWidget::winEvent(MSG *m, long *result)
{
   if (m->message == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
   {
     if ((m->wParam & 0xfff0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
     {
        *result = 0;
        // open About dialog
        about();
        return (true);
     }
   }

  return (false);
}

PRO-file:
LIBS += -lUser32
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me try that out.

Comment: The provided solution works but with the following changes.

`winEvent` isn't supported in Qt 5. It is replaced by `QWidget::nativeEvent` see [QWidget::nativeEvent()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent).

Everything else remains the same.

Thanks once again.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. For others I may add: winEvent is now nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* m, long* result) and you need to cast m with MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(m);